# PHP calendar, view day with mapped events

Tags: php, datetime, calendar

I've googled around and tried a few scripts off of CodeCanyon to see if I can grasp the basics of this, but everything seems to run on javascript.

I simply want a programmatical view of a day with any time mapped against it, this is for a time tracking system which is now pretty much built, except for pulling out the data in a day view.

I just want a list of working hours between 9am - 5pm with the time mapped from my database which is stored in the fields:

Date | Start Time | End Time

These are all in the proper datatime and time formats within MySQL and I'm not sure how this would be done as I can only find tut's on month and week views.

Comment: Did you try [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/)?

Comment: From what I can see this is a javascript calendar, I need something which renders a day view on the page and displays submitted timesheets against that day view so the user can see blocks of time which are missing within the hours of a working day mainly built in PHP.

Comment: post your code and the problem you are getting

Comment: I don't have any code yet, this is in the design phase and at architecture level in order to understand programmatically how to achieve what i'm asking and also if what i'm asking is achievable using PHP only.

Comment: Yes it can be accomplished using php alone. For example you can get the time between 9am and 5pm from mysql using the BETWEEN clause and display the result using php

Comment: Once I have these events, how would they then be mapped onto a HTML grid, FullCalendar does this using javascript, but I've not seen any way using PHP to create a day view say from 9am - 5pm and within that show the events against their respective time stored in the database whilst highlighting time which hasn't been tracked. For example Tom works 1 hour from 9am - 10am, he gets a phone call from a client which last 12 minutes, tom continues to work after this from 10:12am until 11:45am.

Comment: At the end of the day Tom wants to review his time using a day view and spots the highlighted time between 10am  and 10:12am and add this in since it's time he's worked, but has forgotten to add.

Comment: Without any code on your side, it's difficult and it's out of the question scope of SO as well. To display the events from the database according to your question, I assume would be: `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE starttime>='09:00' AND endtime<='05:00'` and show the result using php onto a HTML grid.

Comment: Cheers, I shall put some code together and post back if I hit any barriers, appreciate it's a little difficult to envisage things without code.